# Https interception by Fiddler

Tags: asp.net

How to prevent HTTPS interception by Fiddler?

Comment: I didn't know fiddler could do that.

Answer (score 4):

Fiddler does it's interception by setting up a transparent proxy, the traffic sent to the browser is not signed by the a standard CA but by the custom CA that fiddiler installs when you enable the SSL decryption feature.

It only works because you chose to install the CA certificate on your machine and it would not work without that participation on the part of the end user to voluntarily compromise their security by adding the certificate.

Many corporate proxy servers do the same thing to inspect SSL traffic, but once again, the end  user computer must have the corporate proxy servers' certificate installed on their computer or errors will be produced.

---

To actually answer your question *"Also,is there any solution in .NET using which we can stop this interception?"* [You can check the fingerprint of your certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734695.aspx) (or it's CA) and verify that it is the fingerprint you expected to see, if something like fiddiler intercepted the traffic the fingerprints would not match.

Comment: But any enduser can intercept HTTPS Traffic using Fiddler using that Certificate?

Comment: Yes, but you can never protect yourself against something running on the same machine as your software. There is no way for a user/software to intercept the traffic without running software on the computer the traffic is destined for. If they did run somthing on the computer, well you just broke [the first law of computer security](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc722487.aspx#EKAA).

Comment: Also the certificate is randomly generated per installation, if I have fiddiler installed and you have fiddiler installed, and you intercepted my traffic, the intercepted traffic would still show up as invalid traffic due to being signed by a different (untrusted) CA.

Comment: Thanks for ur help. I am stil have few doubts. Say I have hosted a site abc.com implementing ssl using a original certificate. Still somebody else in internet can intercept my Traffic using Fiddler?

Comment: No they can't, if they did you would get [this error](http://wiki.networksecuritytoolkit.org/nstwiki/images/IE_certificate_error.png). If a certificate is not signed by a ***TRUSTED*** certificate authority the web page will not be displayed. Installing fiddler ***adds it's own certificate to the trusted list to that single computer***. All computers on the planet except the ones that have the special randomly generated certificate(only your computer, rember it's random per install) will show errors.

Comment: So u mean to say Fiddler can intercept HTTPS traffic if only it is been installed in the Web server where the application is hosted?

Comment: No, it can only intercept HTTPS traffic on the client computer ***receiving*** the traffic. If it was installed on the server every client who connected would get that error I linked to earlier. the ***client*** must have the custom CA installed, not the server.

Comment: Then end of the day it can expose my sensitive informations and anybody can modify the request. e.g If a "To" address of an Email is intercepted it could be modified to sent to any other Email address. Then what is the point of using SSL?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29787/discussion-between-user1672097-and-scott-chamberlain)